# IntelliJ - Some application properties are grayed out and unused

Tags: spring-boot, intellij-idea, application.properties

I have Spring Boot application which uses application properties files like so:

**in src/resources:**

- application.properties
- application-dev.properties
- application-prod.properties

**in test/resources:**

- application-test.properties

However, the problem I have is that most of the properties set in **application-test.properties** file and greyed out and marked as Unused properties

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out when you add resources folder to your test, you have to right-click on it > Mark Directory as > Test Resources Root.

After this, my properties are neither greyed out nor marked as unused.